# Google app Engine step 4 deploy app ""hello world" java not recognised

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

im trying to deploy a java starter app called "hello" world and I have done all the steps mentioned in google app engine getting started but the last step I get error Java is not recognized as an internal or external command.

here is the last command

appcfg.cmd -A fareedsproject update target\appengine-try-java-1.0

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the error is that Java is not installed on your system (or that your environment variables have not been setup correctly to locate Java). You will need to fix this first. [[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493966/java-path-set-in-linux)].

Additionally, it looks like you are using the old SDK (from when each part of the Google Cloud Platform and each language had its own, separate SDK). You should install the newer [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/?hl=en), which unifies all the different tools for App Engine, Cloud SQL, Cloud Storage, etc. into a single tool.

When you install the newer SDK, the deployment process is:

```
 # Must be done only the first time to login:
 gcloud auth login

 # Deploys the application module described by app.yaml
 gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```